# Array VLookup Returning Incorrect Value VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to write code that does a vlookup on an array.  This is what I have right now:

```
sub test()
Dim SrcRange As Variant
Dim look as Integer
Dim row_ct as Integer

row_ct = Sheets("Index").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set SrcRange = Sheets("Index").Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(row_ct,3)
look = Application.Vlookup("Tier 1",SrcRange,3)

End Sub
```

Here is an example of the table:

```
Tier    Amount  Location Indicator
Tier 1  1500    4
Tier 2  1200    6
Tier 4  13000   5
Tier 5  1200    7
```

For some reason, no matter what I put as my search criteria, the "look" variable always comes out as 2.  Even if I search a range that is not in the first column. I'm sure there is a logical reason for what is going, I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Try adding `,FALSE` as the forth criterion in the vlookup.

Comment: @ScottCraner Wow, it was that easy... This is my first time working with arrays so I was so set on thinking it was an issue with the array.  Thank you.